# How do I find all solutions to a goal in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

I have predicate P1 that returns values one after the other like this:

```
-? P1(ARGUMENTS, RETURN).
-? RETURN = 1;
-? RETURN = 2;
-? RETURN = 3;
-? fail.
```

I also have another predicate called P2:

```
P2(ARGUMENTS, LIST) :- P1(ARGUMENTS, RETURN),... % SOMEHOW HERE I NEED TO INSERT ALL VALUES OF RETURN TO LIST.
```

How do find all of the values of `RETURN` and assign them to `LIST`?

Comment: Is this related?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445490/expand-a-query-into-a-list-in-prolog

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`findall`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall%2f3) to accomplish this:

```
P2(ARGUMENTS, LIST) :- findall(X, P1(ARGUMENTS, X), LIST).
```

This is related to the [`bagof` function mentioned in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445490/expand-a-query-into-a-list-in-prolog) linked to by Anders  Lindahl.  There is a good explanation on the relationship between the two functions (and a third function `setof`) [here](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_12.html):

> To illustrate the differences consider
>   a little example:
>
> ```
> listing(p).
>
> p(1,3,5).
> p(2,4,1).
> p(3,5,2).
> p(4,3,1).
> p(5,2,4).
> ```
>
> Try the following goals. (The answer
>   displays have been modified to save
>   space.)
>
> ```
> ?- bagof(Z,p(X,Y,Z),Bag).
> Z = _G182 X = 1 Y = 3 Bag = [5] ;
> Z = _G182 X = 2 Y = 4 Bag = [1] ;
> Z = _G182 X = 3 Y = 5 Bag = [2] ;
> Z = _G182 X = 4 Y = 3 Bag = [1] ;
> Z = _G182 X = 5 Y = 2 Bag = [4] ;
> No
>
> ?- findall(Z,p(X,Y,Z),Bag).
> Z = _G182 X = _G180 Y = _G181 Bag = [5, 1, 2, 1, 4] ;
> No
>
> ?- bagof(Z,X^Y^p(X,Y,Z),Bag).
> Z = _G182 X = _G180 Y = _G181 Bag = [5, 1, 2, 1, 4] ;
> No
>
> ?- setof(Z,X^Y^p(X,Y,Z),Bag).
> Z = _G182 X = _G180 Y = _G181 Bag = [1, 2, 4, 5] ;
> No
> ```
>
> The predicates `bagof` and `setof` yield
>   collections for individual bindings of
>   the free variables in the goal. `setof`
>   yields a sorted version of the
>   collection without duplicates. To
>   avoid binding variables, use an
>   existential quantifier expression. For
>   example the goal
>   `bagof(Z,X^Y^p(X,Y,Z),Bag)` asks for
>   "the Bag of `Z`'s such that there exists
>   an `X` and there exists a `Y` such that
>   `p(X,Y,Z)`". `findall` acts like `bagof`
>   with all free variables automatically
>   existentially quantified. In addition
>   `findall` returns an empty list `[]` there
>   is no goal satisfaction, whereas `bagof`
>   fails.