# How to find the minimum value of a prolog variable in O(n) time without high order procedures

Tags: prolog, minimum

So I have an assignment to work on and there is one thing I'm confused about. Here is a similar problem to what I'm trying to accomplish. Say I have these rules:

```
size(3).
size(5).
size(7).
size(1).
size(2).
size(9).
```

And I want to find the minimum of size by taking the value 3 and comparing it to 5, storing 3 and comparing it to 7, then comparing it to 1, storing 1 and comparing it to 2...returning a value of 1.

The only way I can see of doing that without a high order procedure would be some form of backtracking while there are still size(X) values and each time altering the size variable. However, I don't see how you can both backtrack and save the new minimum value. I was wondering if anyone could help put me on the right track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your assignment is intended to make you thinking about the peculiar *control flow* of Prolog, and indeed you are now to the point. I've coded the solution and placed some explanatory comment: fill in the ellipsis to complete the code

```
find_min_size(MinSize) :-
    size(Hypothesis),
    !,  % without this cut the minimum is obtained more times...
    find_min_size(Hypothesis, MinSize).

find_min_size(SoFar, MinSize) :-
    % when I should keep searching?
    ...

% the exhaustive search come to end!
find_min_size(MinSize, MinSize).
```

I don't think in Prolog is possible to get O(N) performance, without 'higher order procedures' ( do you mean findall etc..? ). The code above will run in O(N^2). Indexing can't play a role, because size/1 will restart with unbound variable...

An interesting O(N) alternative is using a failure driven loop and the tech that @false explained so well when introducing [call_nth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400256/874024), (also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390922/prolog-rulex-is-true-if-it-returns-two-or-more-results) a follow up). All of these are in the 'impure' realm of Prolog, though...

**edit** here the failure driven loop

```
find_min_size(MinSize) :-
    State = (_, _),
    (   size(V),
        arg(1, State, C),
        ( ( var(C) ; V < C ) -> U = V ; U = C ),
        nb_setarg(1, State, U),
        fail
    ;   arg(1, State, MinSize)
    ).
```

Comment: Hmm.. Don't quite understand how this should work. Each `size(X)` will split search tree into N different values of `X`. In your `find_min_size/1` you take only first variant and cut-off rest. As I understand `find_min_size/2` should be recursive and pass with new `SoFar` till the moment there is no `size/1` left. But how would you convert parallel branches of `size/1` into sequence? Even if you'll define `find_min_size(H, M):- size(H1), H1 < H, !, find_min_size(H1, M).`  you still actually iterate over all `H1` variants and filter those that improve solution.

Comment: it's very easy: size(X) just restart, but the condition filter out unwanted (again!) -> it's O(N^2)

Comment: I'm trying to say that "indexing" and [tabling](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/yap.html#Tabling) will not help anyway since new `SoFar` will not match with any previous "calls".

Comment: Yes, I understood, and edited the answer. That code it's O(N^2). Now I'm working on the call_nth path...

Comment: @CapelliC: Can't you offer a **generic** solution? nb_setarg/3 should not be spread around user code but rather confined to general library code.

Comment: @false: yes, but the requirement 'without high order procedures' made me to avoid call/N...

Comment: @CapelliC: Everytime nb_* is abused, Prolog loses.

Comment: @false: I must admit I don't know a way to solve the problem in O(N) other than with nb_...

Comment: @CapelliC: Not every requirement stated by OP makes sense. "without high order procedures" That's just nonsensical to demand.

Comment: @false: for a **generic** solution, I'll attempt to optimize aggregate_all, and if I'll succeed, then place as a pack on SWI-Prolog site.

Comment: " Not every requirement stated by OP makes sense. "without high order procedures" That's just nonsensical to demand." I stated it was for homework, I didn't think it made sense. Given what the requirements say on the sheet I'm going to assume the first solution is what was intended. The reason I asked about it in the first place was that I didn't know if it was even possible to do it the way I said given how I understood prolog.
CapelliC, thank you :)